# cant log into google signing issue in release mode for firebase flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I am have a flutter app that uses firebase for auth. sign-in with google works in debug mode, but not in release mode. This is most likely an issue with signing with firebase.

Debug environment - WORKING:

```
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
   }
}
```

Release mode - NOT WORKING (Google Sign in)

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}
 buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
     }
 }
```

I am pretty sure the issue is related to signing. I am using the release keys shown in the google play console [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDsip.png)

and the same keys in firebase, I was sure to update the json file when I made the changes
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evo3B.png)

In Debug mode, I use the debug.keystore keys, while in the release version, I am using the keys generated from the app, which I find in the google play console. they are also found in the signing report in android studio.

So I need help figuring out how to get my release version of the app working with firebase auth. I would appreciate any help anyone can give. Thank you - Joseph

Comment: Did you add internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: I did, google returns an error code 10 when I try to sign in

Comment: Delete the account that you created in debug from firebase auth console. Then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not put all thee keys into firebase, just the private and the one from the google play store, but not the release key

Comment: Can you please Explain what others keys did you use ? all i can find is the App signing key in google play console, where do you get the release one ?

Answer (score 3):

*Try these things and I hope it will solve your problem.*

1. Try to verify your SHA-1 key is still corresponding between your app and
   firebase.
2. Go to your firebase console, download a new version of the
   google-services.json file and replace the former one by it.
3. Delete the account (e.g: user@gmail.com)
   you're trying to connect with from the firebase authentication
   console.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however when I remove any accounts from the authentication page, and I try to sign in again, my accounts pop up on the phone, but when I click my account, google returns an error code 10. The account does not show up in firebase because an error was returned.